# Mongoose populate not provided joined result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

I have two models called TodaysDeals and Products

```
export class TodaysDeal {

    _id: ObjectId;

    @Property({ required: true, type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "ProductsModel" })
    products: Products
}
export const TodaysDealModel = getModelForClass(TodaysDeal);
```

and

```
export class Products {

    _id: ObjectId;

    @Property({ required: true })
    productName: String;
}

export const ProductsModel = getModelForClass(Products);
```

I'm trying to populate the joined data, but i did'nt get the joined result.it has only contain product._id.

here is my code

```
 let data = await TodaysDealModel.find().populate("ProductsModel");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extending on what @Vishnu said: you have 2.5 problems

1. for `populate` you need to use the *field name* instead of the *referenced model name*
2. the model name is not `ProductsModel`, at least not from what your code sample provided, [look here to see how typegoose generates class/model names](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/advanced/models-with-same-name/#typegoose-custom-options-customname) [and here](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/functions/get-name)

and another "smaller" problem is, that you use `Products` as type, where `Ref<Products>` would be correct

your corrected code would look like:

```
export class TodaysDeal {
  _id: ObjectId;

  @Property({ required: true, type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Products" })
  products: Ref<Products>;
}
export const TodaysDealModel = getModelForClass(TodaysDeal);

export class Products {
  _id: ObjectId;

  @Property({ required: true })
  productName: String;
}

export const ProductsModel = getModelForClass(Products);
```

```
let data = await TodaysDealModel.find().populate("products").exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the `populate` method with the field name provided in `TodaysDealModel` model.

Try

```js
 let data = await TodaysDealModel.find().populate("products");
```